# When I build docker image, i want to prevent installing node_modules in my local directory

Tags: reactjs, image, docker, build, local-node-modules

I'm studying using dockers in create-react-app.
I don't want node_modules to be installed in my local directory because I'm running `npm install` inside the docker container, so I only need `package.json` in my directory, right?

But every time I build an image, `node_modules` is automatically installed in the local directory.
I think the build takes a long time to `COPY` this folder.

How can I prevent this?
I created the React app with CRA, I didn't touch any code, I deleted the `node_modules` folder myself.
And I've only created 'Dockerfile.dev' and 'docker-compose.yml'.

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

ENV CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

```
version: "3"
services:
    react:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        ports:
            - "3333:3000"
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        stdin_open: true
```

If I do 'docker-compose up' like this, it automatically creates 'node_modules' in the local directory. How can I prevent this?

Comment: If you're doing initial development of the application – you've just run create-react-app and nothing else – why bring a complex deployment system into it now?  Can you use an ordinary host-based Node environment, and not Docker?

Comment: You are bind mounting the current compose dir to `/usr/src/app` inside the container and then a subpath `/usr/src/app/node_modules` to a docker volume. Docker needs that mount point and creates it. if you have a look from your local machine, that dir stays empty. It only contains the files created in the volume when you look at it from the container.

Comment: I've linked this question to two other questions.  The first is about how to keep Docker from sending itself the host's `node_modules` directory, which will speed up the image build; the second is about why that empty directory gets created.